# Solving a system of two fourth-order ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

I have the following fourth order ordinary differential equations for the functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$:

```
eq1 = b[t]*
    Derivative[1][a][t]^2*(-3.*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[1][b][t] + 
      3.*b[t]*Derivative[2][a][t]) + 
   a[t]*(1.*b[t]^5 + 0.5*b[t]^4*Derivative[1][a][t]^2 - 
      3.75*Derivative[1][a][t]^2*Derivative[1][b][t]^2 + 
      b[t]*Derivative[1][a][t]*(4.5*Derivative[1][b][t]*Derivative[2][a][t] + 
         1.*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[2][b][t]) + 
      b[t]^2*(-0.75*Derivative[2][a][t]^2 - 
         1.*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[3][a][t])) + 
   a[t]^2*(-1.*b[t]^3*Derivative[1][a][t]*
       Derivative[1][b][t] + (7.5*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[1][b][t]^3)/b[t] + 
      1.*b[t]^4*Derivative[2][a][t] + 
      Derivative[1][b][t]*(-7.5*Derivative[1][b][t]*Derivative[2][a][t] - 
         5.*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[2][b][t]) + 
      b[t]*(2.*Derivative[2][a][t]*Derivative[2][b][t] + 
         3.*Derivative[1][b][t]*Derivative[3][a][t] + 
         0.5*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[3][b][t]) - 
      0.5*b[t]^2*Derivative[4][a][t]) == (0.75*b[t]^2*
     Derivative[1][a][t]^4)/a[t]

eq2 = ((18.*b[t]^2*Derivative[1][a][t]^4)/a[t] - 
     12.*b[t]*
      Derivative[1][a][t]^2*(-1.*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[1][b][t] + 
        b[t]*Derivative[2][a][t]) + 
     6*a[t]*(2*b[t]^4*Derivative[1][a][t]^2 - 
        5.*Derivative[1][a][t]^2*Derivative[1][b][t]^2 + 
        2.*b[t]*Derivative[1][a][
          t]*(2*Derivative[1][b][t]*Derivative[2][a][t] + 
           Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[2][b][t]) + 
        1.*b[t]^2*(Derivative[2][a][t]^2 - 
           2.*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[3][a][t])))/b[t]^6 == -24
```

In order to solve them, I use the following code

```
NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, a[1] == 1, b[1] == 1}, {a, b}, {t, 0.5, 10}]
```

Of course, I have tried adding more initial conditions and changed the time interval but none of this works. Mathematica can't solve it and tells me the following:

> "NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations."

> "NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions."

How can I tell Mathematica to solve this system?

Comment: `NDSolve` needs a complete set of initial conditions, in your case 4*2. By the way it is good praxis to `Rationalize` the equations before solving

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, I already know that, but I don't have so many initial conditions to put there. If I do what I was doing until now, which is randomly giving the 8 conditions, Mathematica gives singularity problems. How can I give so much reasonable initial conditions?

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles, where do these DEs come from though? Mathematics, physics?

Comment: @Domen It's in the context of physics. They're the generalization of Friedmann equations when one has two scale factors and a modified gravity with higher curvature terms. None of this can help in order to give reasonable initial conditions, I guess.

Comment: Try `Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {Derivative[4][a][t], Derivative[3][b][t]}]`, which tries to solve for the highest order derivative that I can seen. Neither occurs in `eq2`, so I think you have a problem there in that the highest order derivatives are not determined by the lower order ones. Maybe `NDSolve` can solve the system as a DAE, but I doubt it. Maybe there's a mistake in the set up?

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's a fantastic observation you made there. The problem I face is that the first equation has a dependence in $a,b$ and their derivatives up to third ($b'''$) and fourth ($a''''$) order, but the second equation has only dependence up to third order in $a$ and second in $b$. There shouldn't be any mistake in the set up, I have computed the resulting equations by two separate methods and they coincide, so the two differential equations are correct. The problem is to solve them consistently, which I have no idea about and I'm kinda desperate now.

Comment: If `Solve[{eq1, D[eq2,t]}, {Derivative[4][a][t], Derivative[3][b][t]}]` succeeds, then differentiating the 2nd might satisfy `NDSolve` as far as the ODE system goes. You would still need to give it a sufficient number of ICs.

Comment: It looks plausable to attempt to solve them similar to the eqn $f'=\cos(f')$ using `FindRoot` described in the information when you click on the "I" of the error message.  I tried but not successful.  Maybe worth looking at by others though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It happens the same that in the previous case, Mathematica just gives void. I'll keep trying tho, thanks for your answers.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Could you show all initial conditions you try to use?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sure, ```NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, a[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a''[1] == 0.5, 
  a'''[1] == 0.5, b[1] == 1, b'[1] == 1, b''[1] == 0.5, 
  b'''[1] == 0.3}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 10}]``` was one of my tries

Comment: I finally could experiment: `Reduce[Rationalize@{eq1, D[eq2, t]}, Derivative[4][a][t]]` shows `a` needs to be a constant function. But that implies (`eq2 /. {a -> Function[t, C[1]]}`) the second equation is inconsistent. I think there's a coding mistake somewhere in `{eq1, eq2}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I checked carefully the equations, the coding and the results by two methods. The equations seem to be okay (and reduce to the known cases when the parameters take key values), which makes me even more desperate (it would be perfect if they were wrong, but sadly those are the monsters I have to solve). Your code is interesting, maybe rationalize is introducing some problems there? As you say, $a$ can't be a constant and the two equations have to be consistent. Thanks again.

Comment: You can inspect the rationalized equations...All `Rationalize` does is convert floating-point numbers to exact integers and fractions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Then I don't get it, the rest of it seems to be okay, since it is needed to derivate the second equation as you did. Maybe this is okay and it is just saying that both equations are incompatible together...

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Is it problem from general relativity? Could you give a link to the paper with same equations?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Kind of, it is an extension from general relativity, where instead of the Einstein-Hilbert lagrangian density $\mathcal L = \sqrt{-g}\gamma R$ one has the lagrangian density of higher curvature terms (up to fourth order) given by $\mathcal L = \sqrt{-g}(\gamma R+\alpha R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}-\beta R^2$. If one inserts the FLRW metric $ds^2=-b^2(t)dt^2+a^2(t)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$ and applies the Euler-Lagrange equations for higher derivative Lagrangians, one obtains both equations above for $a$ and $b$. That's the context, but I don't think it helps much for the problem stated.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Could you show expression for Lagrangian as a function of `a,b`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sure, sorry for the delay. The lagrangian as a function of $a$ and $b$ is `Lagrangian = 
 6/(a[t]*b[t]^5)*(\[Gamma]*a[t]^2*b[t]^4*a'[t]^2 + 2*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*b[t]^2*a'[t]^4 + 2*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*a[t]^2*b[t]^2*a''[t]^2 +  2*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*a[t]^2*a'[t]^2* b'[t]^2 + (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^4 + 2*(\[Alpha] - 6*\[Beta])*a[t]*b[t]^2*a'[t]^2)*a''[t] - (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^3*a'[t] + 2*(\[Alpha] - 6*\[Beta])*a[t]*b[t]*a'[t]^3 + 4*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*a[t]^2*b[t]*a'[t]*a''[t])*b'[t])`

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Thank you. What is your setup for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Reasonable values are, for example: $\alpha = 0.5$, $\beta=0.2$, $\gamma=1$

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Thank you. I recompute your action and got same lagrangian. Did you use $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} - 
  \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} + 
  \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot q} = 0$ to derive equations?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you. Yes, I checked the Lagrangian by different methods and it was correct, so I am aware that the problem is in the resulting differential equations, not on the Lagrangian derivation. Yes, one method is the one you say for obtaining the equations of motion, which is using the higher order derivative Euler-Lagrange equations that you posted (in fact, it is curious that you need this equation for $a$, but for $b$ it is sufficient to use the ordinary ones since there's no dependence in $b''$ in the Lagrangian). Any clue about solving the resulting differential equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it mentioned by Axionlikeparticles, the system of equations has been derived from Lagrangian $\mathcal L = \sqrt{-g}(\gamma R+\alpha R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}-\beta R^2)$ in some extension of GR in a case of the FLRW metric $ds^2=-b^2(t)dt^2+a^2(t)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$. To reproduce this Lagrangian we use code

```
n = 4;
coord = {t, x, y, z};
metric = {{-b[t]^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, a[t]^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a[t]^2, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, a[t]^2}};

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];

affine := 
  affine = 
   Simplify[
    Table[(1/2)*
      Sum[inversemetric[[i, 
         s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
          D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
          D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
      1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];
riemann := 
  riemann = 
   Simplify[
    Table[D[affine[[i, j, l]], coord[[k]]] - 
      D[affine[[i, j, k]], coord[[l]]] + 
      Sum[affine[[s, j, l]]*affine[[i, k, s]] - 
        affine[[s, j, k]]*affine[[i, l, s]], {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, 
      n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]];
ricci := 
 ricci = Simplify[
   Table[Sum[riemann[[i, j, i, l]], {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]]

scalar = 
 Simplify[
  Sum[inversemetric[[i, j]]*ricci[[i, j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]];  
Ril2 = Sum[
   ricci[[i, k]] inversemetric[[i, l]] inversemetric[[k, m]] ricci[[l,
      m]], {i, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}, {l, 1, 4}, {m, 1, 4}] // Simplify;

R2 = scalar^2;

L = Sqrt[-Det[
      metric]] (\[Gamma] scalar + \[Alpha] Ril2 - \[Beta] R2) // 
  Simplify
```

As output we have

```
L=1/(a[t]^4 b[t]^6)
  Sqrt[a[t]^6 b[
    t]^2] (-\[Beta] (6 a[t] Derivative[1][a][t] Derivative[1][b][t] - 
       6 b[t] (Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + 
          a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]))^2 + \[Gamma] a[t]^2 b[
      t]^3 (-6 a[t] Derivative[1][a][t] Derivative[1][b][t] + 
       6 b[t] (Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + 
          a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])) + \[Alpha] (9 a[
         t]^2 (Derivative[1][a][t] Derivative[1][b][t] - 
          b[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])^2 + 
       3 (a[t] Derivative[1][a][t] Derivative[1][b][t] - 
          b[t] (2 Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + 
             a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]))^2));
```

From this Lagrangian we can derive equations using $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} -    \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} +    \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot q} = 0$ for $q=a(t)$. Therefore we have

```
eq1 = 
 D[L, a[t]] - D[D[L, a'[t]], t] + D[D[L, a''[t]], t, t] // Simplify;

eq2 = D[L, b[t]] - D[D[L, b'[t]], t] // Simplify;
```

This system is not differ from that discussed above, so the problem of `NDSolve` usage still remains. For example,

```
eqs = {eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}; ic = {a[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, 
  a''[1] == 0.5, a'''[1] == 0.5, b[1] == 1, b'[1] == 1, b''[1] == 0.5};

sols = NDSolve[{eqs /. {\[Alpha] -> 1/2, \[Beta] -> 1/5, \[Gamma] -> 
      1}, ic}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

As output we have messages

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.

NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.

NDSolve::parpiv: Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular.
```

The problem here is that `eq2` is a constraint on `eq1`, not an independent equation. It means, that we can try to solve the system `eq1,eq2,ic` as an optimization problem. For this we need some `ic` consistent with `eq2`. Let check that

```
eq2 /. {a[t] -> 1, a'[t] -> 1, a''[t] -> 1/2, a'''[t] -> 1/2, 
   b[t] -> 1, 
   b'[t] -> 1, b''[t] -> -(21/8)} /. {\[Alpha] -> 
   1/2, \[Beta] -> 1/5, \[Gamma] -> 1}

(*Out[]= 0*)
```

Therefore our new initial conditions are given by

```
ic = {a[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a''[1] == 1/2, a'''[1] == 1/2, b[1] == 1,
   b'[1] == 1, b''[1] == -21/8};
```

To convert `eq1,eq2,ini` into a system of algebraic equations we use the Euler wavelets collocation method described in our [paper](https://doi.org/10.3390/axioms10030165)

```
OEm[m_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[2 m + 
    1] Sum[(-1)^(m - k) x^k Binomial[m, k] Binomial[m + k, k], {k, 0, 
    m}]; UE[m_, t_] := OEm[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^((k - 1)/2) UE[m, 2^(k - 1) t - n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]; 
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 7;
With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
  nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dt = 1/(nn); tl = Table[l*dt, {l, 0, nn}]; tcol = 
 Table[(tl[[l - 1]] + tl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Int3 = Integrate[Int2, t1];
Int4 = Integrate[Int3, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
int3[y_] := Int3 /. t1 -> y;
int4[y_] := Int4 /. t1 -> y;
A = Array[aa, nn]; B = Array[bb, nn];
a4[t_] := A . Psi[t];
a3[t_] := A . int1[t] + c1 ;
a2[t_] := A . int2[t] + c1 t + c2;
a1[t_] := A . int3[t] + c1 t^2/2 + c2 t + c3; 
a0[t_] := A . int4[t] + c1 t^3/6 + c2 t^2/2 + c3 t + c4; 
b3[t_] := B . Psi[t]; b2[t_] := B . int1[t] + d1 ; 
b1[t_] := B . int2[t] + d1 t + d2;
b0[t_] := B . int3[t] + d1 t^2/2 + d2 t + d3;
rule = {Derivative[4][a][t] -> a4[t], Derivative[3][a][t] -> a3[t], 
   Derivative[2][a][t] -> a2[t], Derivative[1][a][t] -> a1[t], 
   a[t] -> a0[t], Derivative[4][b][t] -> b4[t], 
   Derivative[3][b][t] -> b3[t], Derivative[2][b][t] -> b2[t], 
   Derivative[1][b][t] -> b1[t], b[t] -> b0[t]};
eqn1 = a[t]^2 b[t]^6 eq1/6 /. rule; eqn2 = a[t] b[t]^6 eq2/6 /. rule;

rul1 = rule /. t -> 1; bc = ic /. rul1; eqs1 = 
 Flatten[Table[eqn1 /. t -> tcol[[i]], {i, nn}]]; eqs2 = 
 Flatten[Table[eqn2 /. t -> tcol[[i]], {i, nn}]]; var = 
 Join[A, B, {c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3}];
```

The solution of optimization problem is given by

```
sol = NMinimize[{eqs1 . eqs1 + eqs2 . eqs2, 
    bc} /. {\[Alpha] -> 1/2, \[Beta] -> 1/5, \[Gamma] -> 1}, var, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]


(*Out[]= {6.0224*10^-7, {aa[1] -> 0.662598, aa[2] -> 6.6182, 
  aa[3] -> 0.411078, aa[4] -> -4.25886, aa[5] -> 6.38316, 
  aa[6] -> 3.1353, aa[7] -> 3.66257, aa[8] -> -3.99448, 
  aa[9] -> 3.72062, aa[10] -> 1.33545, aa[11] -> 17.4548, 
  aa[12] -> 3.23394, aa[13] -> -2.96937, aa[14] -> 0.864018, 
  aa[15] -> -1.77324, aa[16] -> 1.55967, aa[17] -> -4.07709, 
  aa[18] -> -0.890433, aa[19] -> -1.54841, aa[20] -> -4.37257, 
  aa[21] -> 0.199925, aa[22] -> 6.07787, aa[23] -> 0.84347, 
  aa[24] -> -6.724, aa[25] -> 3.21171, aa[26] -> -0.85385, 
  aa[27] -> 0.273778, aa[28] -> 0.0249634, bb[1] -> -1.18045, 
  bb[2] -> 5.51932, bb[3] -> 0.613343, bb[4] -> -0.346739, 
  bb[5] -> 2.66884, bb[6] -> -10.0235, bb[7] -> -1.77049, 
  bb[8] -> 1.2248, bb[9] -> 0.599704, bb[10] -> 0.700833, 
  bb[11] -> 9.03793, bb[12] -> 2.85301, bb[13] -> -1.2703, 
  bb[14] -> 0.434722, bb[15] -> -4.6445, bb[16] -> -1.74593, 
  bb[17] -> -2.82947, bb[18] -> -1.06695, bb[19] -> -1.26808, 
  bb[20] -> -3.13756, bb[21] -> -0.275597, bb[22] -> -4.31528, 
  bb[23] -> 1.52497, bb[24] -> -5.6961, bb[25] -> 2.06735, 
  bb[26] -> -0.336646, bb[27] -> 0.161848, bb[28] -> 0.0455251, 
  c1 -> 0.013626, c2 -> 1.85716, c3 -> -0.235057, c4 -> 0.481964, 
  d1 -> 1.83272, d2 -> 0.654357, d3 -> -0.0931884}}*)
```

The mean error of optimal solution is about 10^-4. It is not perfect but we can check that

```
bc /. sol[[2]]

Out[]= {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
```

Visualization

```
plot1=Plot[Evaluate[{a0[t], b0[t]} /. sol[[2]]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Using modified `ic` we can extend this solution for `t>1` as follows

```
ic1 = {a[0] == 1, a'[0] == 1, a''[0] == 1/2, a'''[0] == 1/2, 
   b[0] == 1, b'[0] == 1, b''[0] == -21/8};
bc = ic1 /. rul1;
```

This solution looks like
[image: Figure 2]

**Update 1.** We also can use series expansions in a form $a=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kt^k, b=\sum_{k=0}^n b_kt^k$, for example

```
 L = 6/(a[t]*b[t]^5)*(\[Gamma]*a[t]^2*b[t]^4*a'[t]^2 + 
     2*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*b[t]^2*a'[t]^4 + 
     2*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*a[t]^2*b[t]^2*a''[t]^2 + 
     2*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*a[t]^2*a'[t]^2*
      b'[t]^2 + (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^4 + 
        2*(\[Alpha] - 6*\[Beta])*a[t]*b[t]^2*a'[t]^2)*
      a''[t] - (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^3*a'[t] + 
        2*(\[Alpha] - 6*\[Beta])*a[t]*b[t]*a'[t]^3 + 
        4*(\[Alpha] - 3*\[Beta])*a[t]^2*b[t]*a'[t]*a''[t])*b'[t]);

eq1 = D[L, a[t]] - D[D[L, a'[t]], t] + D[D[L, a''[t]], t, t] // 
  Simplify

eq2 = D[L, b[t]] - D[D[L, b'[t]], t] + D[D[L, b''[t]], t, t] // 
  Simplify

ic = {a[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a''[1] == 1/2, a'''[1] == 1/2, b[1] == 1,
    b'[1] == 1, b''[1] == -21/8};
n = 11; A = Array[aa, n]; B = Array[bb, n]; T = 
 Table[(t - 1)^k, {k, 0, n - 1}]; a[t_] = A . T; 
b[t_] = B . T; grid = Range[2/5, 1.4, 1/10];
eqs1 = Table[a[t] b[t]^6/6 eq1, {t, grid}]; eqs2 = 
 Table[a[t] b[t]^6/6 eq2, {t, grid}];
```

The optimal solution is given by

```
sol1 = 
 NMinimize[{eqs1 . eqs1 + eqs2 . eqs2, 
    ic} /. {\[Alpha] -> 1/2, \[Beta] -> 1/5, \[Gamma] -> 1}, 
  Join[A, B], MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(*Out[]= {0.0000233149, {aa[1] -> 1., aa[2] -> 1., aa[3] -> 0.25, 
  aa[4] -> 0.0833333, aa[5] -> 0.438961, aa[6] -> -0.30387, 
  aa[7] -> -0.317073, aa[8] -> 0.125383, aa[9] -> -0.182751, 
  aa[10] -> 0.374697, aa[11] -> 0.0144105, bb[1] -> 1., bb[2] -> 1., 
  bb[3] -> -1.3125, bb[4] -> -1.13918, bb[5] -> 0.613892, 
  bb[6] -> 0.413397, bb[7] -> 0.466893, bb[8] -> -0.199954, 
  bb[9] -> 0.622894, bb[10] -> -0.567313, bb[11] -> 0.0127384}}*)
```

We can compare this solution (doted lines) to solution above computed with Euler wavelets (solid lines) for $t\le 1$ (for $t>1$ the correlation is not so good)

```
Show[plot1, 
 Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol1[[2]]], {t, 0.4, 1.}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Red, Dashed}}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I don't understand the algorithm very well, but it seems (you made a nice debugging there) you obtained a valid solution. Is there any way to avoid using the Euler wavelets collocation method? It seems it works fine, but it is tedious if one wants to set up new initial conditions several times.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles If solution looks nice, then I can organize code in one function with parameters and region specification.

Comment: Yeah, the solution above is physically pathological because one change of signature, but that is because there's an `==0` in the equations and not an `==something` (which has to do with energy content), which is very easy to change. I have tried it in another realistic case and it looks aparently nice. Your proposal is fantastic, I really appreciate it, and that would be awesome. Also, I have a question, why is the method used only valid between 0 and 1 and the `ic` need to be changed in order to obtain `t>1`?

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles The reason is the numerical solution convergence. The Euler wavelets are normalized and orthogonalized on the unit interval $0<=t<=1$. Also for $0<=t<=1$ we have better result compare to $1<t<=2$. It is why we not  mixed two solutions. In practice we can map any interval $0<=t<=T$ to unit interval. Please note that your problem is autonomous, hence we can map  $1<t<=2$ to the unit interval with substitution $t\rightarrow t-1$, it is why new `ic` stated at `t=0`.

Comment: Thank you! I agree, it makes sense. Although, do you know any other easier strategy which doesn't need to rely on this Euler wavelet solution? I have read the paper this days and it is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles See Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: That's incredible! Thank you so much. Howerver, I don't understand two points. In the series expansion case, if one extends the interval to $t=0$ we have a different behaviour from the wavelet method, why is this so? Even more, why the correlation is not good for $t>0$? Which method is more trustworthy? The other question is related to both methods, why are the equations multiplied by $a[t]^2 b[t]^6/6$? I find it a silly question but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please, check that `eq1, eq2` have same multiplier `6/(a[t]^2b[t]^6)`, hence we can exclude  it to increase precision our solution. The Euler wavelets method more precise than other methods.

Comment: I don't get it, because if I solve the equations with the multiplier `6/(a[t]^2b[t]^6)` the solution is different from the case where you exclude it. Thank you for the precision comment. What I don't like is that the solution is highly dependent on the method you use for solving them, but I think it is the price to pay...

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles I think it could be better to play around metric $s^2=-a^2(t)dt^2+(a^2(t)^2+\epsilon b^2(t))(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$ with small $\epsilon$. In this case it is clear that we need some mater equation to close model.

Comment: The key point here is to work with two different functions $a$ and $b$ which in principle have to be different, that's the physically relevant case because then one can compare with the ordinary metric without $b(t)$ (usually reescaled to 1) and check if there is any inconsistency, which would lead to insights in singularities. The matter content can be RHS equal to $-4\Lambda,-\dfrac{\Lambda}{a^3}, -\dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{\Lambda}{a^4}$, those are the three interesting cases for Dark energy, matter and radiation respectively. But it has to be solved with the original metric, which is hard...

Comment: Do you mean `eq1==-4 Lambda`, or `eq2==-4Lambda`?

Comment: Both of them have to be equal to those quantities, which is also true for the other possibilities. Thanl you.

Comment: Any insight? Thank you.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Do you mean solution with Lambda?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do it for the three cases but without the trick of multiplying the common factor and it's not working :(

Comment: I have revisited this problem with a bit of calm and it is surprising that in the cases where we have a non-zero RHS (solution with Lambda) the algorithm doesn't work because of that common factor which now can't be extracted