# Solving a system of two coupled ordinary differential equations up to fourth-order

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I have the following (and terrible) system of ordinary differential equations up to fourth order (one of the equations is like a restriction for the other) for the one variable real functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$:

$0=\frac{-12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a''(t)^2-24 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t) a'(t)^2 b''(t)+60 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 a'(t)^2 b'(t)^2-36 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) b(t)^2 a'(t)^4+6 \gamma  a(t)^2 b(t)^4 a'(t)^2+24 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a^{(3)}(t) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a'(t)-24 b'(t) \left(\gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t) a'(t)^3+2 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t) a'(t) a''(t)\right)+24 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t)^2 a'(t)^2 a''(t)-\Lambda  a(t)^4 b(t)^2}{2 \gamma  a(t)^4 b(t)^4}$

$0=-\frac{8 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 a^{(4)}(t) b(t)^3+12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^3 a''(t)^2-8 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b^{(3)}(t) b(t)^2 a'(t)-120 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 a'(t) b'(t)^3+12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) b(t)^3 a'(t)^4+2 \gamma  a(t)^2 b(t)^5 a'(t)^2+16 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 a^{(3)}(t) b(t)^3 a'(t)+60 b'(t)^2 \left(2 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b(t) a''(t)+\gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t) a'(t)^2\right)-16 b''(t) \left(2 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b(t)^2 a''(t)-5 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b(t) a'(t) b'(t)+\gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a'(t)^2\right)+4 a''(t) \left(\gamma  a(t)^3 b(t)^5-12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t)^3 a'(t)^2\right)-4 b'(t) \left(12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 a^{(3)}(t) b(t)^2-12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t)^2 a'(t)^3+\gamma  a(t)^3 b(t)^4 a'(t)+18 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a'(t) a''(t)\right)-\Lambda  b(t)^7}{2 \gamma  a(t)^2 b(t)^7}$

Where I am using prime to denote derivative with respect to time $t$. In Mathematica they look like this

```
Ec1 = 1/(
  2 \[Gamma] a[t]^4 b[t]^4) (6 \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^4 a'[t]^2 - 
    36 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*b[t]^2 a'[t]^4 + 
    24 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t] b[t]^2 a'[t]^2 a''[t] - 
    12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^2 a''[t]^2 + 
    24 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^2 a'[t] a'''[t] + 
    60 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 a'[t]^2 b'[t]^2 - 
    24 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t] a'[t]^2 b''[t] - 
    a[t]^4 b[t]^2 \[CapitalLambda] - 
    24 ((3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t] b[t] a'[t]^3 + 
       2 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t] a'[t] a''[t]) b'[
      t])

Ec2 = -(1/(
   2 \[Gamma] a[t]^2 b[t]^7)) (2 \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^5 a'[t]^2 + 
    12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*b[t]^3 a'[t]^4 + 
    12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^3 a''[t]^2 + 
    16 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2*b[t]^3 a'[t]*a'''[t] + 
    8 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^3 a''''[t] - 
    120 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3 a'[t]*b'[t]^3 - 
    8 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^2*a'[t]*b'''[t] + 
    b[t]^7 (-\[CapitalLambda]) + 
    60 ((3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]*a'[t]^2 + 
       2 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3 b[t]*a''[t]) b'[
       t]^2 + 4 (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3 b[t]^5 - 
       12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]*b[t]^3*a'[t]^2) a''[
      t] - 4 (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3 b[t]^4 a'[t] - 
       12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]*b[t]^2*a'[t]^3 + 
       18 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2*
        b[t]^2 a'[t] a''[t] + 
       12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^2 a'''[t]) b'[
      t] - 16 ((3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2*b[t]^2*
        a'[t]^2 + 
       2 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^2*a''[t] - 
       5 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]*a'[t]*b'[t]) b''[
      t])

[Alpha] = 1/20; [Beta] = 1/5; [Gamma] = 1; [CapitalLambda] = 1; 

sol = NDSolve[{Ec1 == 0,Ec2== 0, ic}, {a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0,1} ]
```

Here, $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are constants of $O(1)$. Of course, a lot of initial conditions need to be given. Some reasonable initial conditions from the context of the problem are $a(t=1)=b(t=1)=1$, and their first derivatives should be positive $a'(t=1),b'(t=1)>0$ but not so big (0.5, for example). I don't have more information in order to give solid initial conditions for the higher derivatives, but it is reasonable again to choose them positive and the initial condition for the second derivative $b''(t=1)$ can be obtained from the first equation by consistency. One could choose, for example:

```
ic = {a[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a''[1] == 1/2, a'''[1]==1/2 , b[1] == 1, 
 b'[1] == 1, b''[1] == -(103/24)}
```

The problem is that Mathematica is cannot solve this system, giving errors like "NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 1.`; unable to continue.".

I have tried to use AsymptoticDSolveValue too (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html), but it doesn't work. I would like to know if it's possible to know something about the solution of this system, if one can check its singularities, behaviour near $t=0$, etc.

Comment: **solve this system, giving errors like** can you show the full code you used? Including the NDSolve command?

Comment: @Nasser Sure, using the ic from above one can write sol = NDSolve[{Ec1 == 0, Ec2 == 0, ic}, {a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 1} ] and gets the error given in the post.

Comment: Your code is wrong.  You write `\[CapitalLambda][t]` in one place then write `\[CapitalLambda]` on its own with no argument in another place. Besides this, how is NDSolve supposed to solve this if it does not know what this function is? You also have `\[Alpha] , \[Beta]` in there with no numerical values. This will not work for numerical solver.

Comment: @Nasser Of course, I ommited the part of defining $\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\gamma$, that's trivial (I used the configuration 1/20,1/5 and 1). The same with $\Lambda$, it is constant (the $t$ dependence it's a typo in the post, not in the system) and it's value can be set to 1.

Comment: That is what I asked first. To make your code complete. People can't guess what they can't see. I said in first comment **can you show the full code you used?**

Comment: @Nasser This should work: \[Alpha] = 1/20; \[Beta] = 1/5; \[Gamma] = 1; \[CapitalLambda] = 1; sol = NDSolve[{Ec1 == 0,Ec2== 0, ic}, {a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0,1} ]

Comment: The main problem is that NDSolve says `Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve  will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations`. May be someone else will have an idea why it says so for your system.

Comment: @Nasser Yes. In fact, the root of all evil is that one equation depends on $a,a',a'',a''',a'''',b,b',b'',b'''$ and the other only in $a,a',a'',a''',b,b',b''$, so the higher derivatives are not determined by the lower ones. Even more, one could derive the second equation and try to solve it, but it doesn't work either and i am desperate.

Comment: You make it inconvenient and tedious to work with your code:    Correct your code above regarding $\Lambda$, write all the code in one copy-and-paste block including setting up the initial conditions,  include the full `NDSolve` code,  and in a comment block, the error message you're getting so all someone has to do is copy and paste and run it.  Normally good practice to Latex the DE but yours is so messy it's only a distraction.  Consider removing it.

Comment: If you have a system of ODEs where one of the equations is a constraint on the lower derivatives, then it will go better for you if you can figure out what the true degrees of freedom are for the system *before* you feed it into a numerical solver.  You may also need to delve into the [detailed documentation on numerical ODE solvers in Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html), particularly the section on DAE solvers.  Godspeed.

Comment: As I remember we discussed similar problem on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284335/solving-a-system-of-two-fourth-order-ordinary-differential-equations

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, it is a similar system. I have already tried your method to this system but I haven't been able to solve it. Trying other approaches, like doing a naive RKIV or so, can't solve this system because the lower derivatives don't determine the higher ones. It would be amazing if you could help me with this one.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Yes I can, but I need Lagrangian as well. Also I see that my previous answer was not accepted.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am going to accept it now, sorry, I didn't knew how to do it. The thing is that this system doesn't come from a Lagrangian, it comes from the full equations of motion of the theory, the two equations you see right there are the $00$ component and the $ii$ components of the full field equations, but that shouldn't be a problem I think. It is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved as optimization problem with using the Euler wavelets collocation method as follows

```
eq1 = 1/(2 \[Gamma] a[t]^4 b[t]^4) (6 \[Gamma]*
      a[t]^2 b[t]^4 a'[t]^2 - 
     36 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*b[t]^2 a'[t]^4 + 
     24 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t] b[t]^2 a'[t]^2 a''[t] - 
     12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^2 a''[t]^2 + 
     24 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^2 a'[t] a'''[t] + 
     60 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 a'[t]^2 b'[t]^2 - 
     24 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t] a'[t]^2 b''[t] - 
     a[t]^4 b[t]^2 \[CapitalLambda] - 
     24 ((3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t] b[t] a'[t]^3 + 
        2 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*
         a[t]^2 b[t] a'[t] a''[t]) b'[t]);

eq2 = -(1/(2 \[Gamma] a[t]^2 b[t]^7)) (2 \[Gamma]*
      a[t]^2 b[t]^5 a'[t]^2 + 
     12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*b[t]^3 a'[t]^4 + 
     12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]^3 a''[t]^2 + 
     16 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2*b[t]^3 a'[t]*a'''[t] + 
     8 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^3 a''''[t] - 
     120 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3 a'[t]*b'[t]^3 - 
     8 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^2*a'[t]*b'''[t] + 
     b[t]^7 (-\[CapitalLambda]) + 
     60 ((3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2 b[t]*a'[t]^2 + 
        2 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3 b[t]*a''[t]) b'[
        t]^2 + 4 (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3 b[t]^5 - 
        12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]*b[t]^3*a'[t]^2) a''[
       t] - 4 (\[Gamma]*a[t]^3 b[t]^4 a'[t] - 
        12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]*b[t]^2*a'[t]^3 + 
        18 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2*
         b[t]^2 a'[t] a''[t] + 
        12 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^2 a'''[t]) b'[
       t] - 16 ((3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^2*b[t]^2*
         a'[t]^2 + 
        2 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]^2*a''[t] - 
        5 (3 \[Alpha] - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]*a[t]^3*b[t]*a'[t]*b'[t]) b''[
       t]);

\[Alpha] = 1/20; \[Beta] = 1/5; \[Gamma] = 1; \[CapitalLambda] = 1;
```

Let check that initial conditions `ic = {a[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a''[1] == 1/2, a'''[1] == 1/2, b[1] == 1,b'[1] == 1, b''[1] == -515/120}` satisfier to `eq1`, we have

```
 eq1 /. {a[t] -> 1, a'[t] -> 1, a''[t] -> 1/2, a'''[t] -> 1/2, 
  b[t] -> 1, b'[t] -> 1, b''[t] -> -515/120}

Out[]= 0
```

Then we transform `eq1, eq2` to the system of algebraic equations in a form

```
ic = {a[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a''[1] == 1/2, a'''[1] == 1/2, b[1] == 1,
    b'[1] == 1, b''[1] == -515/120};
eqs = {eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0};
OEm[m_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[2 m + 
    1] Sum[(-1)^(m - k) x^k Binomial[m, k] Binomial[m + k, k], {k, 0, 
    m}]; UE[m_, t_] := OEm[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^((k - 1)/2) UE[m, 2^(k - 1) t - n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]; 
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4;
With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
  nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dt = 1/(nn); tl = Table[l*dt, {l, 0, nn}]; tcol = 
 Table[(tl[[l - 1]] + tl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Int3 = Integrate[Int2, t1];
Int4 = Integrate[Int3, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
int3[y_] := Int3 /. t1 -> y;
int4[y_] := Int4 /. t1 -> y;
A = Array[aa, nn]; B = Array[bb, nn];
a4[t_] := A . Psi[t];
a3[t_] := A . int1[t] + c1 ;
a2[t_] := A . int2[t] + c1 t + c2;
a1[t_] := A . int3[t] + c1 t^2/2 + c2 t + c3; 
a0[t_] := A . int4[t] + c1 t^3/6 + c2 t^2/2 + c3 t + c4; 
b3[t_] := B . Psi[t]; b2[t_] := B . int1[t] + d1 ; 
b1[t_] := B . int2[t] + d1 t + d2;
b0[t_] := B . int3[t] + d1 t^2/2 + d2 t + d3;
rule = {Derivative[4][a][t] -> a4[t], Derivative[3][a][t] -> a3[t], 
   Derivative[2][a][t] -> a2[t], Derivative[1][a][t] -> a1[t], 
   a[t] -> a0[t], Derivative[4][b][t] -> b4[t], 
   Derivative[3][b][t] -> b3[t], Derivative[2][b][t] -> b2[t], 
   Derivative[1][b][t] -> b1[t], b[t] -> b0[t]};
eqn1 = a[t]^4 b[t]^4 eq1/18 /. rule; eqn2 = 
 a[t]^2 b[t]^7 eq2/30 /. rule;

rul1 = rule /. t -> 1; bc = ic /. rul1; eqs1 = 
 Flatten[Table[eqn1 /. t -> tcol[[i]], {i, nn}]]; eqs2 = 
 Flatten[Table[eqn2 /. t -> tcol[[i]], {i, nn}]]; var = 
 Join[A, B, {c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3}];
```

Numerical solution

```
sol = NMinimize[{eqs1 . eqs1 + eqs2 . eqs2, bc}, var, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

Visualization solution `a[t], b[t]` with collocation points

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[{a0[t], b0[t]} /. sol[[2]]], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 ListPlot[{Table[{t, a0[t]}, {t, tcol}], 
    Table[{t, b0[t]}, {t, tcol}]} /. sol[[2]], 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

To compute solution at `t>1` we use

```
ic1 = {a[0] == 1, a'[0] == 1, a''[0] == 1/2, a'''[0] == 1/2, 
  b[0] == 1, b'[0] == 1, b''[0] == -515/120}; rul0 = 
 rule /. t -> 0; bc1 = ic1 /. rul0;
sol1 = NMinimize[{eqs1 . eqs1 + eqs2 . eqs2, bc1}, var, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

Visualization

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[{a0[t - 1], b0[t - 1]} /. sol1[[2]]], {t, 1, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 ListPlot[{Table[{t + 1, a0[t]}, {t, tcol}], 
    Table[{t + 1, b0[t]}, {t, tcol}]} /. sol1[[2]], 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: That looks fantastic. Thank you so much. I have a last question, is there any way to check this is the solution to the system? I am thinking in something like `eqs /. sol /. {t -> RandomReal[]}` to correctly check that the system is solved succesfully.

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles This is not solution in ordinary sense, this is optimal solution with an average error of `Sqrt[sol[[1]]/(2 nn)]` for `t<=1`, and  `Sqrt[sol1[[1]]/(2 nn)]` for `t>1`.  You can also check `bc/.sol[[2]]` and `bc1/.sol1[[2]]`.

Comment: Yeah, but that checks are purely for the initial conditions. I guess that you mean that this is not the solution in the ordinary sense but it is an accurate numerical solution for the system, right?

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles This is solution for the system with minimal error as possible, but it is not unique.

Comment: Well yeah, but in my mind if it's the most accurate numerical one then it is the most important. Even more, expanding in series for example (as the other problem we discussed) gives a similar answer, so it is kinda reliable as the true solution. Thank you! I'm wondering one last thing, is it possible to do a series expansion without going trough the Euler wavepackets method and obtaining a similar solution?

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Could you estimate how solution should looks like? Is `a` looks physical one or maybe 'b`?

Comment: In fact both of them are physical. The key point is that $a$, $b$ or both exhibit an expected behaviour: a big crunch scenario. One of them (or both) start with zero size (i.e., we have at early times $a(t)=0$ (or b, or both), the big bang), then both grow until a maximum and then they start shrinking until they reach 0 again, a collapsing big crunch universe. This behaviour can be seen with this method, that's why I think it's correct. In my mind it would have been great to just make a series expansion and give it to the program, but that doesn't seem to work, at least this does

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles We can add boundary conditions at `t=0` and `t=2` as well, for example in a form `a[0]==0,b[0]==0, a[2]==0, b[2]==0`.  Do you like this scenario?

Comment: I have already thought on that, but we shouldn't. The think is to specify the conditions at $t=1$ because it's the time we know (present time), and to predict with the differential equations what happens at $t$ close to 0 (past) and bigger $t$ than 1 (future). If we force the conditions then it is an ad hoc solution, the key is that this behaviour of going to 0 arises naturally,that's the crucial point. By the way, a naive question, why does the numerical solution has to do with minimizing `eqs1 . eqs1 + eqs2 . eqs2`?I would love to know if different methods give similar solutions

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles Unfortunately solution is not unique, so we can't guaranty that we can compute the same solution with different method.  We can guaranty uniqueness  around `t=1` only. The same problem we have in a case of small ball placed on the large ball in a gravity.  If at `t=0` it has equilibrium state, and then at `t>0` it rolls in some direction. With different methods we will compute different directions.  It is why I ask about boundary conditions at `t=0`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem I see. In fact, if I am not correct, something like Runge-Kutta IV can't work with a system like that, right? And yeah, maybe since we can guaranty uniqueness only around $t=1$ the conclusion of reaching zeros of the functions is a bit risky, but it is a common scenario for random initial values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and initial conditions, that's why I think it is realiable. Unfortunately, no conditions can be put on $t=0$, although if I had to put some initial conditions there they would be $a(t=0)=b(t=0)=0$ and their derivatives positive :)

Comment: Also, I am wondering what would the solution look like if by brute force one expresses $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ as a power series of $t$ without using the wavelet minimize method, but again, as in the Runge-Kutta case I told you above, I don't know how to implement that with this system, where one equation is a constrain to the other...

Comment: Again, sorry for the naive question, but why does the numerical solution has to do with minimizing eqs1 . eqs1 + eqs2 . eqs2? It feels kind of arbitrary to me...

Comment: @Axionlikeparticles What do we usually assume is that `eq1==0, eq2==0`. But in a real life for numerical solution we use `eq1==eps1<<1,eq2==eps2<<1`, where `eps1, eps2` are numerical errors. Actually we minimize error of numerical solution.

Comment: I see, but how one knows it has to minimize `eqs1 . eqs1 + eqs2 . eqs2`? Is there an easy way to see it? By the way, yeah, the raw approach of using series expansion doesn't help, in fact `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 2}]` takes a lot of time without giving an answer